# Why can't I delete this face?

Tags: vertices, faces

I'm trying to clean up the letter "k" here and can't delete the faces where I've circled.  I tried selecting the vertices and holding shift, but it just won't select all of them.  How can I do this?  Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Ok I've uploaded.

Comment: I downloaded your file and after converting the text to mesh (alt+c) it allowed me to delete any of the faces I want.  What is it doing when you try to delete it?

Comment: You might find the edge along the bottom of the target face the easiest to select and delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Convert the text to mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Switch to `Face Selection` as shown below

[image]

- Select the face you want to remove, and choose the Knife tool to cut the part you don't want as shown below and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

- Select the part you want to delete then hit <kbd>x</kbd> and choose delete Faces as shown below:

[image]

- Do the same with the other faces and you will get the desired look as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here:[image]

Comment: But for some reason I am unable to select the actual area I want (where I highlighted in my screenshot).  I tried limit selection to visible but no matter how slowly and accurately I try to select the vertices, it just won't do it.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @lakerice answer updated and provided screenshots and an updated .blend file. Please accept and Upvote the answer :)

Comment: Totally worked.  You're a genius @Tak